# Dismiss Modal ViewController Popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, modal-dialog

Here is the case.
I have 2 controllers. In first controller i have normal feedback form on submit of form there is popup(modal). Second controller i am using as modal. I am calling second controller as modal using below code from first controller.

```
popupObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OTPDialogViewController"];
popupObj.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:popupObj.view];
[self addChildViewController:popupObj];
```

Which is working fine. Now i want to dimiss the popup on click of button close which is in second controller. Below code is not helping

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the popupObj view controller to the first view controller as a 'child' view controller.

If you check the documentation for 'addChildViewController:', the corresponding method to dismiss it (the child view controller) is:
- (void)removeFromParentViewController;

Link to: - (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController;
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchildviewcontroller?language=objc

Try this in your popupObj view Controller:

```
- (IBAction)dismissBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

link to: - (void)removeFromParentViewController;
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621425-removefromparentviewcontroller?language=objc

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

this will work for me in swift 4. try on your second view controller button action method

```
 @IBAction func btncClose(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: i tried its not working. I am initiating Modal in first controller and trying to close it by clicking close button in second controller.

Comment: your second controller is model(popup) right? and the close button is on model

Comment: then create the IB action of that button and use the code above this will close the model(popup)

Comment: Yes i tried what you recommended but its not working. Code i tried is [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];